# Partial Differential Equations Course And Differential Geometry Prerequisites

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, advice

Is the ordinary differential equations course a prerequisite for the partial differential equations course for a person who has passed the integral calculus course?
Is it really required to have passed an ordinary differential equations course to be able to learn Fourier Theory?
What is the prerequisite for a person who wants to learn differential geometry and has passed basic linear algebra, single variable calculus?
My problem with most of the available books is all of them are based on introducing pure theorems with very small amount of practice problems, which does not help much to learn to apply those ideas and make them sink in the mind.
I wish someone could explain the set of skills needed to tackle books based on theory than problem solving, since most of them are hard to deal with.

> I expect both guidance and advice on the questions asked, please do not bombard me with list of books that you have googled, instead share your invaluable experiences regarding questions and strategies to reduce wasting time on thinking how to think and learn.

Comment: you can study elementary Fourier series in parallel with second semester calculus. For example, Stewart's calculus has a bonus online section that is quite easy to follow at about 10-20 pages (with answers to the posed problems). For differential geometry, Oneill's text is a well-known classic which takes a more or less computational approach, you can "do" calculations in there which you don't really understand if that's what you're after. I'd provide links, but that would require googling ;)

Comment: You'll need multivariable calculus at some point if you haven't seen that. But after that, does your institution have applied math courses in these, or "advanced math for physicists" sorts of courses? If you're not interested in the formal background and proofs, these would be the way to go. For example, I've seen diff eq. / fourier analysis / complex analysis / special functions taught as a full year course for non-math-majors. But really, we need further info on your background and more on what stuff you want to learn & why. Many of these subjects can be taught at many different levels.

Comment: @aes Well, I would like to study physics, so what I want to learn should be something applicable.In addition, I have some backgrounds in complex analysis, but not that much to be able to solve problems, consider me a student who knows a bit of multivariable calculus and has not taken any real analysis or generally analysis course.